# What lies between polynomial decay of any order and exponential decay?

Tags: real-analysis

I have a quick question. Suppose we have function with:

$$f_1(k) \leq \frac{K_1}{n^k},\quad \mbox{for any } n\in\mathbb{N} $$

and then we have a function:

$$f_2(k) \leq K_2\exp(-k) $$

For a fixed value $n\in\mathbb{N}$, it is clear that $f_2$ decays faster than $f_1$. But the statement is true for any positive integer $n$, can you then not conclude that $f_2$ asympotically decays at the same rate? I was told that this is not true. Can anybody contruct a function which decays slower than $f_2$, but faster than $f_1$?

Comment: The first example is still exponential decay, and it's faster than the second if $n\ge 3$.

Comment: Do you mean $k^n$ rather than $n^k$?

Comment: Yes i mean $k^n$, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

An example of a function that grows faster than any polynomial but slower than an exponential is $k^{\log k} $. This qualifies as the type of decay you are looking for when it is in the denominator.